# Server-Client JAVA socket programming error

Tags: java, sockets

I am new to socket programming and want to create a client that sends a number and server returns the number multiple of number sent by client. I run the server first and then the client. I am entering the value but not getting any response from server. Following is my client and server code.

**Server code**

```
try
        {
        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(4000);
        while(true)
        {
         Socket sock=ss.accept();
        InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
        String num=br.readLine();
        try
        {
            int n=Integer.parseInt(num);
            n=n*2;
            String ret=String.valueOf(n);
            PrintWriter writer=new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
            writer.println(ret);
            writer.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a number!");
        }
        }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
```

**Client code**

```
try
        {
         Socket s=new Socket("127.0.0.1",4000);
        String st;
        PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
        InputStreamReader is=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(is);
        st=in.readLine();
            pw.println(st);
            st=br.readLine();
            System.out.println("the server says: "+ st);
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Please suggest what steps to follow as I am not getting any output from server.

Comment: Any errors on console?

Comment: You are reading from the server using `br.readLine()` before writing any to the socket. You should get the input from standard input using `in.readLine()`, write this to the server socket using `pw.println()` and then read from the server using `br.readLine()`.

Comment: @ Priyesh Thank you, but the server is still not responding accordingly. It is showing the output as the number entered by the client. For e.g. If I am entering `2`, then server is also responding `2`.

Comment: Either step through your code using the debugger or add log outputs. So you can analyze what data has when which value.

Comment: I still cannot get the problem.

Comment: @Nambari I don't have any error in console but the server is giving the same output as the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with this part of the client code, which sends `st` via `pw` and then claims `st` is the server's output.

```
pw.println(st);
System.out.println("the server says: "+ st);
```

You should be able to fix the problem actually getting a value from the server via `br`. You also need to flush `pw`:

```
pw.println(st);
pw.flush();
st = br.readLine();
System.out.println("the server says: "+ st);
```

Alternatively, you can make `pw` auto-flushing like so:

```
PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);
// ...
pw.println(st);
st = br.readLine();
System.out.println("the server says: "+ st);
```

Comment: I have tried doing this. It is conceptually correct and so I will modify the aforementioned code but I am still not getting any response from the server.

Comment: I think the server is not reading the value that client has passed. Can there be any error in this code segment in the server code: `int n=Integer.parseInt(num);
            n=n*2;
            String ret=String.valueOf(n);`

Comment: Did you make any corrections? It is not working on my machine.

Comment: @KomalJoshi yes, the new version should flush `pw`.